# ListView with an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create an ArrayAdapter for my ListView to display a list of Contacts, but it is saying that it cannot resolve the constructor for the array adapter. Please can someone help me and tell me if I need to create a custom adapter or not. I have also tried ArrayAdapter> but that doesn't resolve the constructor either. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.contactmanagement;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int ADDCONTACT_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    int idCounter = 0;
    List<Bundle> contacts = new ArrayList<Bundle>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        contacts.add(bundle);
        String fname = bundle.getString("fname");
        String lname = bundle.getString("lname");
        String full_name = fname + " " + lname;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactList);

        ArrayAdapter<List> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<List>(this, R.layout.textview, contacts);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        /*
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText(fname +" " + lname);
        textView.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter++;
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent contactDetails = new Intent("com.example.contactmanagement.ContactDetails");
                int counterID = v.getId();
                Bundle bundleToPass = contacts.get(counterID);
                contactDetails.putExtras(bundleToPass);
                startActivity(contactDetails);
            }
        });
        layout.addView(textView);
        */
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddContact.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADDCONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

}
```

Comment: hey try your code by declaring array adapter as string.ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<List> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<List>(this, R.layout.textview, contacts);
```

to this:

```
ArrayAdapter<Bundle> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bundle>(this, R.layout.textview, contacts);
```

For an `ArrayAdapter`, the type that you place between the <> is the type that is used for your array.

In this case, your `List` is actually a list of Bundles, which means **contacts** is simply a list of type `Bundle`.

Therefore, the type you place in the <> has to be of type `Bundle` to match the type of your contacts list.

The reason for you getting that constructor error is because you wrote `ArrayAdapter<List>` so the constructor was expecting **contacts** to be an `Array` or `List` of type `List`.

One extra thing to note is...

Your ArrayAdapter probably won't give you the output you expect, because it doesn't know what to do with `Bundle`.

If it was simply a list of `String`, then it'll know to display that into the layout of `R.layout.textview`, but for type `Bundle`, it simply won't know what you wish to do with it unless you create a custom adapter to handle this type.

So you can either create a custom adapter to allow your ListView to know how to display the contents of your Bundle, **or** if your info is simple enough, *like just a single String*, then you can create a new List that holds only that simple String and pass that in to the constructor for the ArrayAdapter instead.

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly. Now for the hard part of figuring out how to unpack this bundle

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if it has answered your question.

Comment: For your hard part, this is something that can only be done through a custom adapter.